# Compilation error when trying to set autoCompleteTextView adapter to null in ant build

Tags: android, ant, android-build

I am trying to build an apk with ant everything and the compilation fails with this error message:

```
[javac]  type parameters of <T>void cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds android.widget.ListAdapter,android.widget.Filterable
[javac]             currentAddressTextView.setAdapter(null);
```

In eclipse it compiles fine, and when I remove that part of code it compiles as well during the ant build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try below:

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
     currentAddressTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Yea I will try that, but even adapter.clear() doesn't work as well.

Comment: @themilkman: When adapter is null then how `adapter.clear()` will work?

Comment: I mean instead of calling setAdapter(null); just calling adapter.clear();

Comment: @themilkman: clear has different behavior than removing the adapter itself(setting null). I am not sure of your purpose by setting the adapter to null. Whis adapter are you using and what error are you getting when calling `clear()`? Can you share the relevant code fragment?

Comment: well the null 'trick' worked, and it was an ArrayAdapter.
thanks.